# How can an object-oriented language support hot reloading of classes?

Tags: object-oriented

Consider an object-oriented language like Java. Typically, when a class is modified and recompiled, the software which uses that class must be closed and restarted, and the program state may need to be saved to disk in order to be restored.

However, it is theoretically possible that an implementation could allow "hot reloading" of classes at runtime. This would be beneficial for availability in long-running software such as a networked servers, and also potentially useful for interactive debugging ─ you would not have to restart the program to try out changes.

To be clear, the idea here is not just that new instances created after the update will use the new class. The idea is that when the class is updated, existing instances of the old class are migrated to become instances of the new class, including any changes required to their memory layouts. For example, new fields added to existing objects could be initialised with some default value, or perhaps the language could have a mechanism allowing the user to control how existing objects are re-initialised.

How could hot reloading of classes work in practice, and what would its limitations be?

Comment: Dart is one language I know that supports this

Comment: @mousetail I'd definitely be interested in an answer about how Dart handles this.

Comment: Java allows dynamic loading of classes at runtime; i use that in the unit tests for my Vyxal to JVM compiler

Comment: @Seggan Yes, but as far as I know, existing objects would still be associated with the old version of the class. Perhaps there is some way to do it in Java by replacing the class pointer in the object's header? If there is an example of this being done in practice (perhaps using `sun.misc.unsafe`?) it would make for a good answer.

Comment: you can `putInt` (at address 8, for the klass word) but all your code will still think that the values are of the old type. note that even if you just change the implementation of a method that already existed, calling it without a cast will return garbage. `unsafe.putInt(obj, 8, newKM); (NewClass)obj` *should* work fine though.

Comment: Objective-C lets you mess with the dtable at runtime, and it works because literally every method call is dynamic. This is a surprisingly well-documented thing, though I’ve only seen it used for DI.

Comment: Is this asking about this in the *debugger* or as a language-level feature? Production IDEs do have this in the debugger already and it works moderately ok sometimes.

Comment: @MichaelHomer As a language-level feature is more interesting, but answers about debuggers which support this are fine too (particularly if there is a shortage of practical examples from real languages that support it as a language-level feature).

Comment: What about setting implicit conversions and being lazy about the conversion, only when the old type is used would you need to change it, so you might update them lazily, you'd need strong runtime reflection capabilities though. Shortly you might save the old class and each of its iterations and set up an implicit conversion pipeline made possible by storing migrations (setting default fields etc.). The limitations to this would be that you would have to type check at runtime every single call which would probably have a sizeable impact to performance and the load would increase every iteration

Answer (score 9):

## The Objective-C Runtime

Objective-C has surprisingly strong runtime reflection capabilities, on par with that of JavaScript. Here's a couple ways you could do it with the Objective-C runtime library.

### Option 1: Register and deregister classes

Objective-C lets you create new classes at runtime with [`objc_allocateClassPair`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418559-objc_allocateclasspair?language=objc), and deregister existing classes with [`objc_disposeClassPair`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418912-objc_disposeclasspair?language=objc). Whenever a class needs to be reloaded, you could register the new version as a new class and dispose the existing one. The problem with this approach is, as per the documentation for `objc_disposeClassPair`:

> Do not call this function if instances of the `cls` class or any subclass exist.

However, you can change the class of an object at runtime with [`object_setClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418905-object_setclass?language=objc). Therefore, you could still use this approach with the following process:

1. Allocate, configure, and register the new version of the class.
2. Iterate over all instances of the old version of the class, and change them to the new version. Objective-C doesn't have an "all instances" function in its runtime, so this would have to be a static property on the class.
3. Dispose the old version of the class.

### Option 2: Mess with the class metadata

This allows you to work without having to worry about subclasses or iterating over existing instances, but may be much more involved. You'd have to check each part of the definition individually.

#### Methods

To change the implementation of an existing method, use [`method_setImplementation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418707-method_setimplementation?language=objc) or [`method_exchangeImplementations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418769-method_exchangeimplementations?language=objc). This is a well-supported pattern known as *method swizzling*; as I mentioned in a comment, this is usually used for dependency injection.

To add new methods, use [`class_addMethod`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc).

Removing methods is actually not something that's not supported! If you're making a new language, you could probably add support for this in your language, but Objective-C doesn't have it. However, there is a way for an object to pretend like it doesn't have a method, even at compile time, so we can use the same technique here.

The first step is to write the method implementation as follows:

```objectivec
- (void)exampleMethod {
  [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
}
```

[`doesNotRecognizeSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418637-doesnotrecognizeselector?language=objc) is the method invoked by the runtime when all attempts to find the implementation of a method have failed. `_cmd` is an implicit argument that all methods take, which is the method's *selector* (a representation of the method name).

The second step is to make [`respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector?language=objc) and [`instancesRespondToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418555-instancesrespondtoselector?language=objc) also deny it:

```objectivec
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
  if (sel_isEqual(@selector(exampleMethod), aSelector)
    return NO;
  return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}

+ (BOOL)instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
  if (sel_isEqual(@selector(exampleMethod), aSelector)
    return NO;
  return class_respondsToSelector(self, aSelector);
}
```

Then, you can drop these in with the functions mentioned above.

#### Properties

*Properties* are the public interface used to access instance members, while *ivars* are the underlying storage for them. Changing properties is fairly straightforward: [`class_replaceProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418891-class_replaceproperty?language=objc) to change an existing one and [`class_addProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418946-class_addproperty?language=objc) to add a new one, while deleting old ones is basically in the same boat as deleting methods. Each property corresponds to a pair of selectors (e.g. `foo` for the getter and `setFoo:` for the setter).

#### Ivars

This is where things get interesting. Messing with ivars means changing the actual memory layout of the class. Surprisingly, this is just supported: [`class_setIvarLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418749-class_setivarlayout?language=objc) for owned ivars and [`class_setWeakIvarLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418852-class_setweakivarlayout?language=objc) for weak ones. You may have to take care that existing instances don't become dangerous when you do this.

#### Protocols

*Protocols* are Objective-C's equivalent of Java's interfaces. Once again, adding new ones is supported but removing existing ones is complicated. Adding a new one is just a call to [`class_addProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418773-class_addprotocol?language=objc) plus implementing the necessary methods.

You can't remove the protocol from the class list, but you can make the class act like it's not there by overriding [`conformsToProtocol:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418893-conformstoprotocol?language=objc)

```objectivec
+ (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol {
  if ([protocol isEqual:@protocol(ProtocolToRemove)])
    return NO;
  return class_conformsToProtocol(self, protocol);
}
```